# Is the QED equation of motion for the wavefunction just the Dirac equation?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, wavefunction, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation, second-quantization

In the [QED wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics#Equations_of_motion), they derive the equation of motion under the Lagrangian, using the classical Euler-Lagrange equation.  This gives

$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi = e\gamma^\mu A_\mu\psi.$$

Isn't that just the Dirac equation?  Or if not, how is it different?  So then, are the Dirac and QED Lagrangians identical, and the only difference is that QED does the whole path integral instead of just the path of stationary action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't that just the Dirac equation? Or if not, how is it different?

Yes, it is the Dirac equation for a charged fermion interacting with the electromagnetic field.

> So then, are the Dirac and QED Lagrangians identical, and the only difference is that QED does the whole path integral instead of just the path of stationary action?

Exactly. The Dirac equation is often mentioned in the context of Relativistic Quantum Mechanics, in which case the wavefunction is a classical field. Meanwhile, QED considers a quantum field, which will lead to more complex corrections. For example, the two theories will yield different values for the electron's anomalous magnetic moment, which was one of the first successes of QED over the simple Dirac theory.

> the only difference is that QED does the whole path integral instead of just the path of stationary action

Let me also mention that this is a hell of a difference. It makes the theory incredibly more complicated, since now you are working with quantum fields. It gets much richer from the mathematical point of view ($\psi$ now is not a function of spacetime, but an operator-valued distribution) and QED actually matches experimental data, while the Dirac equation alone doesn't (in today's precision).

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful.  Though I must say, I always see that term "operator valued distribution" thrown around, but I don't see why wrapping $\psi$ up in a path integral should make it a fundamentally different mathematical object, since it was just an innocent Dirac spinor before.  Or is it just an equivalent formulation that's somehow more convenient?  (And the same qualm about the Grassmann number, I suppose)

Comment: @AdamHerbst These questions might deserve a post of their own, but I'll try to summarize it in here. Inside the path integral, you can treat the field variables as usual c-numbers or Grassmann numbers (depending on the commutation relations desired), but ultimately you want to use the path integral to obtain expressions related to a quantum theory, and hence you are just rewriting expressions that would otherwise be written in terms of a Hilbert space. In this Hilbert space, the fields are operators

Comment: Inside the path integral, $\psi$ is just a spinor, but it represents an operator acting on a Hilbert space. These are two equivalent views on QFT/QM: one is the Hilbert space approach, the other is the path integral approach. They sound different and think in different ways, but are equivalent.

Comment: Now for Grassmann numbers. If you use a path integral with c-numbers, you'll get the field operators in the Hilbert space satisfying the canonical commutation relations. This is excellent for bosons, but terrible for fermions. To get the canonical anticommutation relations needed for fermions, the variables that go into the path integral must be Grassmann variables.

Comment: (as I said, these questions deserve a post of their own. I tried to summarize the ideas in here, but the comment section is surely not ideal for this)

Comment: Okay, well I really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: By the way, I asked [this other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/743363/230823) as a follow-up (although not about the above issues), so maybe you could weigh in on that one.